# Keep custom sort order in issues list

Tags: youtrack

I have created a backlog of issues, and I can rearrange the issues in the list. But when I've ordered them according to priority, can I save that order? If I re-sort the list by date, how can I go back the custom sort order again?

Answer (score 2):

I've found that the best way to order issues is to use fields for sorting, and then to use a custom search that includes a *sort by*. I add a milestone version field and use values for that field that will sort alphabetically (eg. 'gva-v1.4', 'gva-v1.5'). These values correspond to sprints. Then I go to the agile board to focus in on that sprint and drag & drop my issues to sort them within the sprint.

Otherwise, sort order established by drag & drop doesn't seem to be sticky, except within the context the sorting was established. Sort order is sticky within an agile board for a particular sprint, but is not sticky when you cross over to the issues page. And within the issues page I've given up relying on drag & drop sort order being maintained. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! We tried to understand the stickiness, but have also introduced a separate "Importance" field, which we sort by now. That works well, although it's a pity that the drag and drop couldn't be stored in a more stable way.